# How to stop water leaking along tile seam under a frameless shower door sweep?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower, leak, seal

I have a frameless glass bathroom shower and water leaks under it.  I believe the water is moving along a tile to tile seam (like subway tiles) and going under the sweep.  It is fairly new construction and I don't want to remove the tile and tilt it back toward the shower.  Can I use clear caulk and fill the seams?  Is there a better fix?  I'd really appreciate some advice.

I've update the question with a picture: (Thanks for the suggestion @JACK)  [image: Tile seam under door sweep]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the problem area?

Comment: Is your new construction warranty still in effect?  This should be covered and in my opinion, caulk is NOT the correct solution.  Clearly there is either a design or an installation issue that is allowing water to go where it should not go.  Caulk will fail in a relatively short time and you will be looking at hidden water damage over the long term.